# Issue while transferring control from one JSP to another?

Tags: jsp

While hyperlinking JSP page to another page i used the below code :-

```
<TD width = "290px">
   <a href="connectivityteam15.jsp?Site_name=<%=resultset.getString(1)  %>">
     <font size="3"> <%= resultset.getString(1) %> </font>
</TD>
```

In one such case `resultset.getString(1)` value was `"Presales & support team"`.

In `connectivityteam15.jsp` I fetched the value of `Site_name` as.

`request.getParameter("Site_name");`

Result is displaying only `"Presales"`.

Is their any way to pass the exact datas to another JSP using href?

Comment: you should look how to send a `space` into a URL.

Comment: I think that the problem is with '&' in your value. That has to be encoded